# Why does "Cannot GET" appear when I access the page on google using node, but the route in React works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building an application with Reactjs and Nodejs and I've built all my routes using React-Router-Dom

`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>

    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/receitas' element={<Receitas />} />
    <Route path='/receita/:id' element={<ReceitaPage />} />
    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='/crud' element={<Crud />} />
    <Route path='/ebook/:id' element={<EbookPage />} />

  </Routes>

</BrowserRouter>`
```

When I move between my pages using the front-end buttons, the site works correctly because either I use the functionality `<Link to={}> </Link/>` or I use `UseNavigate();`.

But I'm having problems when I access the site directly with the link, I'll show you a picture of when I use the button on the page: [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/130ue.png)

When I access the same link writing in the browser itself, this message appears to me: [Second Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6Zr.png)

The browser recognizes it as another type of route.

I'm using Nodejs for my Back-End and I really don't know what to do about it. Can anyone help me, why I don't know if I can fix it using Reactjs or Nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you rendering your React build using NodeJS? If so, you'll have to instruct your backend to always render index.html.

You'll have to do something like this in your server:

```
// Handle React routing, return all requests to React
app.get('*', function(req, res) { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html')); 
});
```

Comment: Hey, I think I am, I am using this line of code to give me my page: `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/build')));
`.  And I tested what you said and it worked! Thank you so much, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you write directly in the browser it is retrieving the route from the node server. On the other hand, when you navigate using the react router link it's doing client side routing and never hits the server.

If you plan on doing all of the routing with react router, you can add a catch-all in the node server for all routes that will always return the single page HTML index.

Assuming you are using express, you can do something similar to this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('path/to/your/index.html');
});
```

Comment: hey, I am using Express, and I tested your solution, but it didn't work. I don't know how to show you the error, but it says `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`. I think this error may be appearing because I'm rendering my page using Nodejs.

Comment: you probably need to import `path` and use join to form the correct path `path.join(__dirname, 'your-directory', 'index.html')`